# Property 'selectionStart' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, selection-api

I am using `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` in order to get the starting and ending point of a text selection.

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-gareth-mr04o

However, I am struggling to defined the type of the event on which they can be called on.
If I use `any`, the code works properly but I would prefer to know the right event.

I tried with these types:
`Element`
`React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement>`
`<HTMLDivElement>`
with no luck

```
export default function App() {
  const [startText, setStartText] = useState<number | undefined>();
  const [endText, setEndText] = useState<number | undefined>();

  const handleOnSelect = (event: any) => { <--- I CANNOT FIND THE RIGHT EVENT TYPE
    setStartText(event.target.selectionStart);
    setEndText(event.target.selectionEnd);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container direction="column" className="App">
      You can type here below:
      <TextField
        value={"This is a example, select a word from this string"}
        onSelect={(event) => handleOnSelect(event)}
      />
      <br />
      <Grid item>The selected word starts at character: {startText}</Grid>
      <Grid item>The selected word ends at character: {endText}</Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a tricky one because the material-ui `TextField` component involves multiple nested nodes.  The argument that is passed to the `onSelect` function is a `div`.  However the event itself occurs on an `input` inside the `div`.

```
const handleOnSelect = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>) => {
    console.log(event.target, event.currentTarget);
};
```

This logs the `input` and then the `div`.

Using `event.currentTarget` gets very specific Typescript information.  We know that it is an `HTMLDivElement`.  But the `div` doesn't have the properties `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` that we want to access.  Those exist on the `input`.

`event.target` gives us a very vague type for an `EventTarget`.  We don't know that the target is an `input`.

One option is to verify the element at runtime.

```
const handleOnSelect = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>) => {
    if ( event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement ) {
        setStartText(event.target.selectionStart);
        setEndText(event.target.selectionEnd);
    }
};
```

Since you know that the event will always occur on an `HTMLInputElement`, I think it's safe to make an assertion.

```
const handleOnSelect = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>) => {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    setStartText(target.selectionStart);
    setEndText(target.selectionEnd);
};
```

Note that `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties use `null` instead of `undefined`.  So you'll want to either change your state type to `<number | null>` or replace `null` with `undefined` by using null coalescing `event.target.selectionStart ?? undefined`.

Comment: Many thanks! I opted out for `const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement` since the if-clause was always skipped (`event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement`)